# confusion about Spring Data Flow Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm confused about Spring Cloud Data Flow Server deployment...

We are planning to run it on cloudfoundry, and [the instructions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-cloudfoundry) say one should download the final server artifact (a jar) and deploy it.

On the other hand [another section in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-security-cloud-foundry-sso) describes a way on how to customize the provisioning of roles to users with some custom code. But there is no explanation on how to embed the server in a custom application so I can provide my code (via `@Bean`).

On a [very old blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/05/1-stream-2-applications-and-3-dependencies-for-spring-cloud-data-flow) I found a mention of `@EnableDataFlowServer` but this annotation is not described in the official documentation anymore - is it still valid?

There is also no way described how I could use any other security then oauth, do I really need to use oauth? how about using my own security config or even only basic authentication?

I kind of expected the same flexibility as spring cloud config server provides...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Spring Cloud Data Flow [site](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/cloudfoundry/) on how to install SCDF on Cloud Foundry. The instructions in this site have the correct information set up SCDF on CF.

The `@EnableDataFlowServer` is intended for customizing Spring Cloud Data Flow server using/overriding the existing `DataFlowServerAutoConfiguration` and `DataFlowControllerAutoConfiguration`. This is not specific to CF though.

Comment: I know `@EnableDataFlowServer` is not specific to CF, but none of the things I ask above is described on the site you mention (except the standard installation), e.g. is `@EnableDataFlowServer` still valid? how do I embed SCDF so I can use my custom security configuration?  how do I run SCDF on my local env when I want to use `@EnableDataFlowServer`? what dependencies do I need to include (it is not available on start.spring.io)?  are there any examples with `@EnableDataFlowServer`?...

Comment: Currently, I don't see documentation on this and created https://github.com/spring-io/dataflow.spring.io/issues/119 for this. You can find an example of its usage in one of the tests here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/config/DataFlowServerConfigurationTests.java#L157

Comment: Hi, @domi. Sorry that we don't have any concrete documentation on this subject yet. We have recently added a [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/2d0c3cd5d77c85015834e1fbb411759dbe67a41b/custom-dataflow-builds/dataflow-server-21x#examples-for-custom-data-flow-server-build) to demonstrate how to customize SCDF-server, and the sample uses `@EnableDataFlowServer` model to extend the default behavior. Feel free to use that as the reference to get things going on the security customizations.